# Explain the meaning of $\alpha$ in a Kolmogorov-Smirnov two-sample test

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

The Wikipedia article on the [two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov.E2.80.93Smirnov_test) states that:

> The Kolmogorov–Smirnov test may also be used to test whether two
>   underlying one-dimensional probability distributions differ. In this
>   case, the Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic is
>
> $$D_{n,n'}=\sup_x |F_{1,n}(x)-F_{2,n'}(x)|$$
>
> where $F_{1,n}$ and $F_{2,n'}$ are the empirical distribution
>   functions of the first and the second sample respectively. The null
>   hypothesis is rejected at level $\alpha$ if
>
> $$D_{n,n'}>c(\alpha)\sqrt{\frac{n + n'}{n n'}}.$$

It is not clear to me the meaning of the *$\alpha$ level*. Where does it come from and what does it mean statistically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The level $\alpha$ is the "significance level" of the test, the rate of [Type I error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors), the probability of detecting a difference under the assumptions of the null hypothesis (that the two samples are drawn from the same distribution).

Comment: No problem, I deleted the comment. It's like when we are 5% confident to believe in H1 ;).